# Function is not doing simple console logs as a test, don't know why

Tags: javascript

Yesterday I had a same question. However it got downvoted because I didn't provide enough information, couldn't edit in time. Today I tried again and singled out what I was trying to do and now I can give the complete code example, cause it still has the same issues.

So this time, this is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <link href="styles/styleAllOverAgain.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Tic Tac Toe!</h1>
    <button id="start/restart">Start/Restart</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button id="opponentToggle">Against Computer</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <form id="nameSubmit1">
        <input id="input1" type="text" placeholder="Player 1 name:">
        <button id="submit1" type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
    <br>
    <input id="input2" type="text" placeholder="Player 2 name:">
    <button id="submit2" type="submit">submit</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button id="play">Play!</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="gameplayButtons">
        <button id="1">1</button>
        <button id="2">2</button>
        <button id="3">3</button>
        <button id="4">4</button>
        <button id="5">5</button>
        <button id="6">6</button>
        <button id="7">7</button>
        <button id="8">8</button>
        <button id="9">9</button>
    </div>
    <script src="javascript/myscriptAllOverAgain.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS is really small at this point:

```
#gameplayButtons {
    display: grid;

    grid-template-columns: 75px 75px 75px;
    grid-template-rows: 75px 75px 75px;
}
```

And my javascript:

```
function myImmediateFunctionSetUp () {
    // 'use strict';

    let gameBoard = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];
    let playerName1 = "";
    let playerName2 = "";
    let entered1 = false;
    let entered2 = false;

    const getPlayerName1 = document.querySelector("#submit1");
    getPlayerName1.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        entered1 = true;
        // const inputText = document.querySelector("input1");
        // playerName1 = inputText.nodeValue;
        console.log("hello");
        console.log(entered1);
        // inputText.setAttribute("placeholder", playerName1);
    })
}

myImmediateFunctionSetUp();
```

I was trying to "remember" the name by storing it in the placeholder after submitting it. Didn't do that. Then I deleted everything to see if it would do console.logs. And it's not
doing that either. I really don't know what's causing that.

If anyone saw my post yesterday, it was a Module Pattern. Today I tried removing that part and try a normal "named" function and it's not working either. So I've narrowed it down as much as I could, removing all the other event listeners and only singled out this one. And I really don't know what to do.

Comment: So you have a function called `myImmediateFunctionSetUp`, but you don’t appear to be _calling_ that function anywhere. So what exactly did you expect to happen now?

Comment: Maybe because you should call your `function myImmediateFunctionSetUp ()`. Right now it's just a function. Not one part of your code did not call that function

Comment: The variables in your function should be declared with `const` or `let` as appropriate. The selector in your `.querySelector()` call is incorrect.

Comment: Okay... a couple of really dumb mistakes. But it is still not displaying the log tests. I've got let for the variables. I've called the function with () behind it. And I edited the selector to have # in front of it. I've edited the post with how it now looks.

Comment: Yes I did. I'm now stepping through it with the devtools. Then when paused it is showing the console.logs. However if I unpause they disappear again.

Comment: @Niels , I have given solution to your problem .Please have look at it.

Comment: I have looked at it... I just think this behaviour is really strange. Just now it showed the out comment when I tried that as well. However now that doesn't stick either. Seems like everything is immediately errased. So your problem isn't the solution either. Could it be some kind of setting? By the way I did copy all of it. However the logs don't stick at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried another button. And that one worked. So I narrowed it down to the form element which wasn't doing anything. I had already tried that, but not after removing some silly mistakes pointed out to me here. Me trying again after correcting those worked though. And everything seems responsive again.

So it is fixed by removing the form element.

Thanks for the suggestions! And I will leave this for anyone else having console log problems or something similar.

The end code looked like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <link href="styles/styleAllOverAgain.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Tic Tac Toe!</h1>
    <button id="start/restart">Start/Restart</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button id="opponentToggle">Against Computer</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input id="input1" type="text" placeholder="Player 1 name:">
    <button id="submit1" type="submit">submit</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input id="input2" type="text" placeholder="Player 2 name:">
    <button id="submit2" type="submit">submit</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button id="play">Play!</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="gameplayButtons">
        <button id="1">1</button>
        <button id="2">2</button>
        <button id="3">3</button>
        <button id="4">4</button>
        <button id="5">5</button>
        <button id="6">6</button>
        <button id="7">7</button>
        <button id="8">8</button>
        <button id="9">9</button>
    </div>
    
    <script src="javascript/myscriptAllOverAgain.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And javascript:

```
function myImmediateFunctionSetUp () {
    // 'use strict';

    let gameBoard = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];
    let playerName1 = "";
    let playerName2 = "";
    let entered1 = false;
    let entered2 = false;
    
    const getPlayerName1 = document.querySelector("#submit1");
    getPlayerName1.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        const inputText = document.querySelector("#input1");
        playerName1 = inputText.value;
        // console.log("hello");
        // console.log(entered1);
        inputText.setAttribute("placeholder", playerName1);
        inputText.value = "";

        entered1 = true;
    })

    const opponentTogg = document.querySelector("#opponentToggle");
    opponentTogg.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        console.log("test2");
    })
}

myImmediateFunctionSetUp();
```

CSS stayed the same.

Answer (score 1):

`document.querySelector("submit1")` is not going to return any elements. `submit1` is not a valid selector for `.querySelector(...)`.

Use either `document.querySelector("#submit1")` or `document.getElementById("submit1")` and your code will work fine

Comment: I've changed that. Now... when I step through with the devtools debugger it does show them. But when unpaused they disappear again. Seems like I'm getting closer though...

Answer (score 0):

You can check jsfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/0qkygsz4/
I added some improves and I have console.log working

```
function myImmediateFunctionSetUp () {
    // 'use strict';

    gameBoard = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];
    playerName1 = "";
    playerName2 = "";
    entered1 = false;
    entered2 = false;

    const getPlayerName1 = document.querySelector("submit1");
    var el = document.getElementById('submit1');
    if(el){
        el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        entered1 = true;
        // const inputText = document.querySelector("input1");
        // playerName1 = inputText.nodeValue;
        console.log("hello");
        console.log(entered1);
        // inputText.setAttribute("placeholder", playerName1);
        });
    }
}

myImmediateFunctionSetUp ();
```

Comment: That's weird. I just copied your entire code and it isn't showing the console logs for me. It does seem to work on fiddle though.

Comment: I can see them flashing by though... They just don't stay.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to solved your issue. Might be not best solution

```js
window.onload =  function myImmediateFunctionSetUp () {
    // 'use strict';

    gameBoard = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];
    playerName1 = "";
    playerName2 = "";
    entered1 = false;
    entered2 = false;
console.log("Out");
    const getPlayerName1 = document.querySelector("#submit1");
    getPlayerName1.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    // Prevent page refresh.
    e.preventDefault();
        entered1 = true;
        // const inputText = document.querySelector("input1");
        // playerName1 = inputText.nodeValue;
        console.log("hello");
        console.log(entered1);
        // inputText.setAttribute("placeholder", playerName1);
    });
}
```

```css
#gameplayButtons {
    display: grid;

    grid-template-columns: 75px 75px 75px;
    grid-template-rows: 75px 75px 75px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <link href="styles/styleAllOverAgain.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Tic Tac Toe!</h1>
    <button id="start/restart">Start/Restart</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button id="opponentToggle">Against Computer</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <form id="nameSubmit1">
        <input id="input1" type="text" placeholder="Player 1 name:">
        <button id="submit1" onClick="myImmediateFunctionSetUp" type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
    <br>
    <input id="input2" type="text" placeholder="Player 2 name:">
    <button id="submit2" type="submit">submit</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button id="play">Play!</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="gameplayButtons">
        <button id="1">1</button>
        <button id="2">2</button>
        <button id="3">3</button>
        <button id="4">4</button>
        <button id="5">5</button>
        <button id="6">6</button>
        <button id="7">7</button>
        <button id="8">8</button>
        <button id="9">9</button>
    </div>
    <script>
    
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope, your problem is resolved

Comment: Doesn't work. The logs don't stick. And neither does the commented section where it should "remember" the name in the placeholder. So no answer is the correct one yet... still remains unsolved...

Comment: Also you appear not to have the script linked. But it seems to make no difference. Nothing is showing up on my console anymore. Not inside the evenlistener, not outside it. On some previous version, a completely different set of files... it still logs some tests. But not in these ones.